# What is the keyboards key combination that produces the signal "Ctrl-^" in VIM?

Tags: vim, keyboard

I was reading the VIM Help text [":help ls"](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html) and there says:

> "Each buffer has a unique number.  That number will not change, so you can always go to a specific buffer with ":buffer N" or "N CTRL-^", where N is the buffer number."

I know that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> produces <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, but a don't know what keys combination should produce <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>^</kbd>.

My keyboard layout is `Brazilian 107-key ABNT2 Windows keyboard` and the keys combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> (hat) does not produce <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>^</kbd>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `<Ctrl-6>`

from vim help:

```
Mostly the ^ character is positioned on the 6 key, 
pressing CTRL and 6 then gets you what we call CTRL-^.
But on some non-US keyboards CTRL-^ is produced in another way.
```